Cant locate c wire for my ecobee thermostat
I purchased this old home and I was trying to upgrade my thermostat to a smart ecobee thermostat but I couldn't locate my C wire on this old circuit board.
Here's the model of the circuit board: Goodman B18099 13 Furnace Control Board 1012 933D 1012 83 9337A.





what tracing have you done already? and where did you get stuck?

C should be pin 6 of molex connector, you should be able to trace it to a grounded lead on transformer.



I can't see real well due to dust on the transformer and wires blocking the molex connector, but it looks like the Red off the transformer is the +24, confirm that it goes to pin 3. Then maybe two Violet leads come off the transformer, one is probably connected directly to pin 6, if either of those Violets have a tap you can add to it, but you may have to cut one to make a new tap.

or use a piggy-back faston at the transformer, or connect the c wire to the ground screw,  the rules for ELV wiring are fairly permissive.
